# I need some assistance in putting an IF statement in this PLSQL function

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I need to put in IF statement which returns a specific student id "999999" when the current student cannot be found by first and last name. Here is what I am currently working with:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret_student_id INT;
SELECT 
    student_id
INTO ret_student_id FROM
    students
WHERE
    first_name LIKE var_first_name
        AND last_name LIKE var_last_name;
    RETURN ret_student_id;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it to the value before your select.
The select does not update your value if there is nothing in the select.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE ret_student_id INT;
  SET ret_student_id=999999;
SELECT 
  student_id
  INTO ret_student_id FROM
  students
WHERE
  first_name LIKE var_first_name
      AND last_name LIKE var_last_name;
RETURN ret_student_id;
END
```

Comment: This is a very efficient and simple solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This SELECT statement raises a NO_DATA_FOUND exception when not exactly one row is found.

```
BEGIN
   SELECT ...
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN 999999;
END;
```